# How to apply pager in a table using theme function?

Tags: 7, paging

I am rendering and displaying data using theme table. I'm using

```
   $form['pager'] = array('#theme' => 'pager');
```

for displaying pagination. Now my intention is to display pager in two areas of screen. One is above the theme table and another one is below. I placed this code two times but pager is coming only once.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Sorry, but you would need to learn basics of PHP first. Especially how arrays works and what array indexes are for.

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have enough information to help. Where does the $form come from? You mentioned a theme table, how do you construct it? Sql query? Views? Other? In which files are you working? Etc..

Comment: hey it's alright.. i fixed this issue.. Tx for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added  the below lines in above and below theme table script.

```
     $form['pagerTop'] = array('#theme' => 'pager'); and 
     $form['pagerBottom'] = array('#theme' => 'pager');
```